# Calculating the shipment prices

Tags: java, android

Hi can someone throw a help with this project?

Implement in Android the mobile application offered by a transport company to calculate the price of your shipments.
The company calculates the price of the shipment based on three concepts: area, weight and urgency.

a) First, a fixed cost is applied according to three different zones
• Zone A: Asia and Oceania: € 30
• Zone B: America and Africa, € 20.
• Zone C: Europe € 10

b) The cost variable on the weight is added to the fixed cost:
• If the package weighs up to 5kg, it charges € 1 / Kg
• Between 6 and 10 Kg is charged at 1.5 € / kg.
• Starting at 10Kg, it costs € 2 Kg.

c) If the package is urgent, an increase of 30% is applied to the price calculated up to that moment (fixed area cost + euros / kilos)

[image: photo of design]

Comment: You'll need to show us what you've tried in order for us to help you.

Comment: how can I put the code?

Comment: Edit the question and paste your code there.